# Simplify react component and make it better

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to add some optional costs for products, but I can't find a simpler way than this... I also don't know how to exactly formulate the question, so if anyone has an idea, I would gladly rename it... this is the code I want to simplify (i would like to automate the process for every item, for eg. do this for every item in array:

```
const extrasList = [
{name: extra1, price: 100, active: false},
{name: extra1, price: 100, active: false},
{name: extra1, price: 100, active: false}
]
```

):

1.Extras.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styles from "../styles/extras.module.css";

function Extras() {

  const [extra1, setExtra1] = useState(false);
  const extraItem1 = extra1 === true ? 20 : 0;

  const [extra2, setExtra2] = useState(false);
  const extraItem2 = extra2 === true ? 40 : 0;

  const extrasPrice = extraItem1 + extraItem2;

  return (
    <div className={styles.extrasWrapper}>
        <p className={extra1 === true ? styles.activeExtras : styles.extras} onClick={() => setExtra1(!extra1)}>Extra1 {extraItem1}</p>
        <p className={extra2 === true ? styles.activeExtras : styles.extras} onClick={() => setExtra2(!extra2)}>Extra2 {extraItem2}</p>
      </div>
  );
}

export default Extras;
```

2. Extras.module.css

   ```
   .activeExtras {
        color: red;
    }

    .extras {
        color: white;
    }

    .extrasWrapper {
        display: flex;
        gap: 0.2em;
    }
   ```

Comment: Is there something here that doesn't work? "Better" is really subjective, and not on-topic for StackOverflow (but maybe for the CodeReview stackexchange site, check out their rules).

Comment: You got to understand how booleans work: `extra === true` is completely redundant, as a condition already checks for truthiness. Change your ternaries to `extra ? 40 : 0` (or whatever).

Comment: Better is subjective, but this sure looks at first glance like something I'd make a component for and then `map` for the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a separate component and 1 state to maintain all extras and update them accordingly based on click. Assuming the name is unique. Check the components you can use.

```
function Extras(props) {
  const [extrasList, setExtrasList] = useState(props.extrasList);

  const toggleExtra = (extra) => {
    const updatedExtrasList = extrasList.map((ex) => {
      if (extra.name === ex.name) {
        ex.active = !ex.active;
      }
      return ex;
    });
    setExtrasList(updatedExtrasList);
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.extrasWrapper}>
      {extrasList.map((extra) => {
        return (
          <p
            key={extra.name}
            className={extra.active ? "activeExtras" : "extras"}
            onClick={() => toggleExtra(extra)}
          >
            {extra.name} {extra.active ? extra.price : 0}
          </p>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

From your parent component pass extrasList props.

```
const extrasList = [
  { name: "Extra1", price: 100, active: false },
  { name: "Extra2", price: 200, active: false },
  { name: "Extra3", price: 300, active: false }
];
return (
  <div className="App">
    <Extras extrasList={extrasList} />
  </div>
);
```

Working sample https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-http-3iy5d8